# some css properties arn't working

Tags: html, css

this is my page code sample

```
<body>
<div id="header">
<?php
include 'includes/header.php';
?>
</div>
    <div id="loginpage">
    <div class="data">
        <h5><?php echo $errors ;?></h5>
            <form  class="loginform" action="login.php" method ="post">
         <h5>UserName:</h5>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="s" placeholder="username"  required="required"/><br>
        <h5>Password:</h5>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="s" placeholder="password" />
        <br>


        <input type="submit" id="searchSubmit" value="submit" />
            </form> 
     </div>

<img src="login.jpg" width="400px" height="380px"/>

</div>
<?php
include 'includes/footer.php';
?>
</body>
```

and this is my css rule

```
#loginpage
{
width:100%;
height:auto;
background:white;
display:-moz-box;
-moz-box-orient:horizontal;
position:relative;
}
.data {
width:300px;
height:250px;
margin:50px;
margin-top:100px;
padding:10px ;
text-align:left;
background:#e8fccc;
position:relative;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px rgb(0,0,0 0.1) ;

}
#loginpage img{
margin:50px;
border-radius:10px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px rgb(0,0,0 0.1) ;
}
.loginform{
margin-top:50px;
}
```

now problem is css nt working properly in  div data(class)
i defined its height 250px bt it is taking the same height of the img tag.
height is changing when i am incresing or decresng the height of img tag

Comment: What are you expecting?

Comment: if you can show a live link it would be helpful. Plus using terms that are also elements as class names is confusing and can cause you all sorts of headaches. Try using .inputContainer or something that is easily differentiated.

Comment: use "#" before the background-color value, like this: #e8fccc. you forgot this

Comment: the height is not working .data div. want it wuld be 250px but it's height become 380 px as the img tag

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want it to take shape of the elements inside add `overflow:hidden;` to the .input class

Also, you have to add # in front of your color or it won't work.

so black 000000 should be #000000 without the # it's no good.

also this is bad practice
`margin:50px; margin-top:100px;`

if you want 50px margin all around and 100px just on the top you should do `margin:100px 50px 50px 50px` thats top right bottom left.

Comment: input is a class name of a div. and  some css prperties of this div not working. this is my problem

Comment: right, i updated my answer, if you don't specify what to do in the event that data overflows your div it'll just stretch out or overflow. but the image isn't even in the `.input` div as specified in your example so it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: the image is still outside of the `.data` div. that shouldn't have any effect on it.

Comment: this is the problem .data div not taking the difined height 250px;
it is taking the same height that i defined in img tag 380px

Comment: the height for data is going to look like 375px because you have 250px height on it and a 100px margin-top on it and 10px padding all around it adding 20px to the height and a 5px shaddow thing on the bottom. but i can assure you it's not taking shape of an element that's not even inside of it.

Comment: remove the margin-top but height remains same !!

Comment: height is changing when i am incresing or decresng the height of img tag

Answer (score -1):

Remove `class="input"` in that div `<div class="input">`

And use

```
input { //without the dot
    width:300px;
    height:250px;
    margin:50px;
    margin-top:100px;
    padding:10px ;
    text-align:left;
    background:e8fccc;
    position:relative;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px rgb(0,0,0 0.1) ;

}
```